# How to split an array of objects into multiple normal arrays where each array is populated by one property's values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
var GOM = [{name:"Kuroko",ability:"misdirection"},
           {name:"Kise",ability:"perfect copy"},
           {name: "Akashi", ability: "emperor's eye"}];
```

Is it possible to split it into 2 arrays using some predefined function in lodash or native javascript(not forEach).

```
["Kuroko","Kise","Akashi"] and ["misdirection","perfect copy","emperor's eye"]
```

I know I can just do this:

```
var names = [];
var abilities = [];
GOM.forEach(function(member){
  names.push(member.name);
  abilities.push(member.ability);
});
```

but I am looking for another way.

Comment: yours is not a bad way... for what reason you are looking for another way?

Comment: What's wrong with `forEach`? Are you looking for some out-of-the box method that does this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with forEach. I was just wondering if there was another predefined function to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is nothing shorter then two pluck's from lodash:

```js
var data = [
  {name:"Kuroko",ability:"misdirection"},
  {name:"Kise",ability:"perfect copy"},
  {name: "Akashi", ability: "emperor's eye"}
];

var names = _.pluck(data, 'name');
var abilities = _.pluck(data, 'ability');

alert(JSON.stringify(names, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Combine [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map), [values()](https://lodash.com/docs#values), and [unzip()](https://lodash.com/docs#unzip) into a wrapper:

```
var wrapper = _(GOM).map(_.values).unzip();
```

Then it's easy to grab the names:

```
wrapper.first()
// → [ "Kuroko", "Kise", "Akashi" ]
```

And abilities:

```
wrapper.last()
// → [ "misdirection", "perfect copy", "emperor's eye" ]
```

Comment: +1 but be aware that [`_values()`](https://lodash.com/docs#values) doesn't guarantee order, so it might not be usable depending on the code requirements.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works well for this:

```js
var GOM = [{name:"Kuroko",ability:"misdirection"},{name:"Kise",ability:"perfect copy"},{name: "Akashi", ability: "emperor's eye"}];

var names = GOM.map(function(item) {
  return item.name;
});
var abilities = GOM.map(function(item) {
  return item.ability;
});
alert(names + '\n' + abilities);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is just fine, but if you're looking for something more "functional," there's always `reduce`:

```
var GOM = [ { name: "Kuroko", ability: "misdirection" },
            { name: "Kise", ability: "perfect copy" },
            { name: "Akashi", ability: "emperor's eye" } ];

var result = GOM.reduce(function(memo, member) {
  memo.names.push(member.name);
  memo.abilities.push(member.ability);
  return memo;
}, { names: [], abilities: [] });

console.log(result.names);
// => [ "Kuroko", "Kise", "Akashi" ]

console.log(result.abilities);
// => [ "misdirection", "perfect copy", "emperor's eye" ]
```

Comment: So the second parameter of reduce creates and initializes properties on the arguments of the first function?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce